# Is there any way to create a textview with different color or with different styles in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, textview

I was learning DataStore in android development and in my project user will write a name in first activity.

[image: in this activity]

and when user clicks button goes to second activity and my problem starts here:

[image: my activity looks like this]

but i want to show it like these photos:

[image: this is an option]

or like this photo

[image: this is i want to do more]

I mean i want to make name colorful,but not in order,randomly

**what i have tried:**
**i tried to take my name string to foreach but i could not change char colors** my opinion was in foreach loop give any random color to every char but i could not.
then i tried **SpannableStringBuilder** and i get the result and these are my codes:

```
 var random = Random()
        var number1 = random.nextInt(value?.length?.minus(1) !! )
        var number2 = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            random.ints(number1,value?.length !!).findFirst().asInt
        } else {
            TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < N")
        }
        val spannableString = SpannableStringBuilder(value)
        spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                               number1,number2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        textViewName.text = spannableString
```

i use just red color now but if i can make it randomly,i can make with other colors.
i hope you understand my problem and thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already figured out how to apply span to a specific character, for random colors you can simply make a list of colors as follows

```kotlin
val colorList = arrayListOf(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK)
```

and so on and while you are assigning the span you can simply go like this

```kotlin
val randomColor = colorList.random()
colorList.remove(randomColor)
spannableString.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(randomColor),
                               number1,number2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Comment: thanks but this code will make it in order like if green comes from random range number1,number2 it will be green i don't want it to be continously.

Comment: @BarneyStinson Maybe remove the element after it is set, you can remove it from the list or array list once you have got it. Ensuring it won't repeat

Comment: can you look at my third and forth images i mean like this even if we remove it there won't be pattern like these images

Comment: What kind of a pattern do you want @BarneyStinson There is no defined pattern in those images. Removing them will ensure a random color everytime for every character